# .less files in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, less, bower

I have a newly created ASP.net 5 MVC 6 project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.  The guys as Microsoft have made great strides improving the built in UI support for Bower, Grunt etc.  So I decided it was time to figure out using less instead of css.  Seems like it should be easy now, but I can't find any good how to articles for doing this in VS 2015 Update 2 with all the nice new UI elements.

Is there a good write up somewhere?  Is it easy or do you still need to manually create entries in various json files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by installing the extension [WebCompiler](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c). It compiles your .less files into css, including the minified version, every time you build or make a change and save.

All you have to do is to add your .less files into your Content folder, right-click on them and select **Web Compiler > Compile file**. This only operation is only needed the first time you add a new less file.

The extension will add a json file to your solution called **compilerconfig.json** where you can set a few configuration parameters, like for example if you also need the minified version or not.

If you set it up all correctly, you will see this in your Task Runner Explorer:

[image]

Comment: The question I have about this approach is that it seems this is independent of the new way of using Bower, Grunt etc.  Currently in my project in the Task Runner Explorer I see tasks to clean:ccc, clean:js, min etc.  I would expect to see something for less in there as well if I have it all configured correctly, right?

Comment: Correct. I added a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot.